# Multiple lines from single column using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm have a dataframe as like below. I need to graph based on region, date as x Axis and AveElapsedTime as y axis.

```
     >avg_data
             date  region AveElapsedTime
    1  2012-05-19 betasol           1372
    2  2012-05-22  atpTax           1652
    3  2012-06-02 betasol           1630
    4  2012-06-02  atpTax           1552
    5  2012-06-02     Tax           1552
    6  2012-06-07 betasol           1408
    7  2012-06-12 betasol           1471
    8  2012-06-15 betasol           1384
    9  2012-06-21 betasol           1390
    10 2012-06-22  atpTax           1252
    11 2012-06-23 betasol           1442
```

If I rearrage the above one based on region, it will be as like below. It should not plot if there is no value(NA) for particular date.

```
            date atpTax betasol  Tax
    1 2012-05-19     NA    1372   NA
    2 2012-05-22   1652      NA   NA
    3 2012-06-02   1552    1630 1552
    4 2012-06-07     NA    1408   NA
    5 2012-06-12     NA    1471   NA
    6 2012-06-15     NA    1384   NA
    7 2012-06-21     NA    1390   NA
    8 2012-06-22   1252      NA   NA
    9 2012-06-23     NA    1442   NA
```

I tried using the below ggplot command, I'm getting geom_path error.

```
    ggplot(avg_data, aes(date, AveElapsedTime)) + geom_line(aes(col=region)) + opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
    geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

    > str(avg_data)
    'data.frame':   11 obs. of  3 variables:
     $ date          : Factor w/ 9 levels "2012-05-19","2012-05-22",..: 1 2 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...
     $ region        : Factor w/ 3 levels "atpTax","betasol",..: 2 1 2 1 3 2 2 2 2 1 ...
     $ AveElapsedTime: int  1372 1652 1630 1552 1552 1408 1471 1384 1390 1252 ...
```

Please advise on this.

Comment: I strongly suspect that your date got turned into a factor, and that `ggplot2` is now complaining because each point on the x axis is being treated as a separate group.  What are the classes of the columns (i.e. results of `str(avg_data)`)?  Can you use `avg_data <- transform(avg_data,date=as.Date(date))` ?  Or, brute force solution, add `group=region` to your `geom_line` mapping.

Comment: It is working fine, If I transform as date. But is there a option to display all the dates which is there in the date column ?

Comment: you can probably use `+scale_x_date(breaks=...)` to specify this (see `?scale_x_date`), or you can use `group=region` as suggested by me (above) and @Andrie (in his answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you need to specify the `group`. Like this:

```
ggplot(avg_data, aes(date, AveElapsedTime, colour=region, group=region)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: The message indicates almost nothing, as always in R.